# Elegant way to export variables from module in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I want to export one variable after initialized by parameters from one module  in `Node.js`.

Now, there are three options for me.

**Option 1**: with `exports` directly

```
// moduletest.js

exports.init = function(v, w) {
    // actually, the value of a and b could be initialized by other functions.
    // here is one example, simply assign them with v and w just for test
    exports.a = v;
    exports.b = w;
}
```

The variable `a` and `b` could be used out of the module.

```
// app.js
require('./moduletest').init(3, 1);

var ff = require('./moduletest');

console.log(ff.a);
console.log(ff.b);
```

**Option 2**: var one `get` method in the object.

```
var MyObject = {
    init: function(a, b) {
        this._a_ = a;
        this._b_ = b;
    },

    getA: function () {
        return this._a_;
    },
};

exports.mod = {
    valA: MyObject.getA,
    init: MyObject.init
}
```

The variable `_a_` could be accessed by `getA` method.

**Option 3**: through one `get` method in the function prototype.

```
var Test = function (a, b){
    this._a_ = a;
    this._b_ = b;
};

Test.prototype.getA = function()
{
    return this._a_;
}

exports.mod = Test;
```

Here I have two questions:

- Which one is more elegant way to do that?
- If none of above three options is better, is there any better ways?

Comment: Option 1 is a kind of suicide. Why would you use it?

Comment: @skypjack, update this question ...

Comment: What does it mean? Do you want me to update your question? I don't get you, sorry.

Comment: @skypjack, sorry to mislead you. I have updated my question and add the usage of option 1.

Comment: Ok, one more question and I'll answer. Do you want to have a single instance of your exported variable(s) or let the users of the library to create new objects on demand?

Comment: @skypjack, one single instance

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments to your question, a possible approach is the one below. Yours have mainly the problem that you don't actually hide the data, thus letting the user to modify them.

```
module.exports = function (_a, _b) {
    return function() {
        var obj = { };
        Object.defineProperty(obj, 'a', {
            get: function () { return _a; }
        });
        Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b', {
            get: function () { return _b; }
        });
    };
}
```

You can use it as it follows:

```
var factory = require('file_above')(your_a, your_b);
// code
var instance = factory();
// you cannot modify a or b on instance!!
```

Something similar can be done by using the `bind` method of a function and so on. Keep in mind that there is a plenty of possible solutions and none of them is the right one, while almost all of them are valid ones.

As far as I see, anyway, the ones you posted above have some minor issues, even though all of them work fine, of course.